# How to enable Pages for Github Repository using API

Tags: c#, github-pages, octokit.net

This is the C# code using Octokit I am using for Github client and to create the repository, but I am unable to configure it to website enable which we can do manually from the settings of the repository.

```
var productInformation = new ProductHeaderValue(GitHubIdentity);
var credentials = new Credentials(username, password, AuthenticationType.Basic);
var client = new GitHubClient(productInformation) { Credentials = credentials };
```

This is link for API https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net

Comment: The file are 4 years old.  I suspect the TLS version is wrong.  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues.  This June Microsoft pushed a security update that disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 and now requires using TLS 1.2./1.3.  So client code had to be modify to specify the TLS version.  Best was of verifying is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fid

Comment: the issue is not with this code, but actually i want to acheive is to change the settings of repositry to web-pages.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you are changing manually?

Comment: i want to create repository and  upload files, which is working fine using API, now i want to make this repository to work as static site using GitHub Pages site. i am unable to do this step using the API above.

Comment: See following : https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/main/OVERVIEW.md